# IONIC 7.1.1 y Angular - Error al ejecutar comando 'Ionic build' desde consola de MAC

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic

Error:
An unhandled exception occurred: missing ) after argument list
See “/private/var/folders/20/my8cd2vs5_x5dspwqddmk4500000gn/T/ng-dxSOc6/angular-errors.log” for further details.

An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

```
ng run app:build exited with exit code 127.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

any information usefull at verbose…

node version 18.16.0 LTS
ionic CLI —> 7.1.1
angular/CLI —> 15

**Al hacer el build desde Windows no tengo ningun problema, pero necesito ejecutarla también en el MAC para generar los archivos para la versión de IOS. Imposible poder ejecutar el Build con los MISMOS paquetes y misma versiones de todo...**

Comment: El mensaje de error dice que hay más detalles en cierto archivo de log, pero has olvidado incluir la información relevante de dicho archivo en tu pregunta. De la misma manera has olvidado incluir la información adicional que hay al correr el comando con el flag `--verbose`, o al menos mencionar que no ha proveído nada útil, pero que si lo has hecho.